# flutter: Pie chart has a weird margin around it. How can I remove it?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use the piechart widget from the flutter_charts dependency in my flutter app but it has a margin around it taking up space inside the container widget please how can I remove the margin or padding around the pie chart.
How can I remove margin or padding from the PieChart() widget

Comment: You should share some of your code so that we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had faced the same problem but for me that one is due to the improper ratio of defining height and width on its parent widgets. Try to use 1:1 ratio for pie chart. because it always try to align on center.

Answer (score 6):

use `layoutConfig` property of PieChart

```
 layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
   leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
   topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
   rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
   bottomMarginSpec:charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use transform instead of margin

Container(
     transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-230.0, 0.0, 0.0),
child:new charts.PieChart()
)